# How to use '/=' to ensure the elements in the array are unique?

Tags: erlang

I want to ensure the elements in the array are unique.

```
4> A=[1,2, 3].
[1,2]
5> lists:nth(1, A) /= lists:nth(2, A).
true
6> lists:nth(1, A) /= lists:nth(2, A) /= lists:nth(3, A).
* 1: syntax error before: '/='
```

Unfortunately the '/=' does not work in the prompt #6 when I extend it to a three or more elements use case.

What is the acceptable erlang syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if a list contains duplicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000986/how-can-i-detect-if-a-list-contains-duplicates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i guess proper way is to make set from the list and then compare set size and list length. Kind of

```
A = [1,2,3].
S = sets:from_list(A).
length(A) == sets:size(S).
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array has a fixed, compile-time known length (then you should use tuples) and you can pattern-match it:

```
case A of  %% Size = 3
    {_,X,X} -> true;
    {X,_,X} -> true;
    {X,X,_} -> true;
    {_,_,_} -> false
end
```

Otherwise, I guess you'll go [this very inefficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002265/1418165).